# Exporting image from imageCollection.reduce

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I'm trying to export to an asset an image containing a single band, the 90th percentile of LST of 1 year of MODIS. I'm using this script :

```
var inColl = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD11A1')    
inColl = inColl.filterDate('2000-02-24', '2001-02-23')
print(inColl.first())
inColl = inColl.map(function (img){return img.select('LST_Day_1km').multiply(.02)})
var yrPrcntl = inColl.reduce(ee.Reducer.percentile([90]))                          

var pt = [9.15, 42.0742];
Map.centerObject(ee.Geometry.Point(pt), 10);

var palette = ['00008F', '0010FF', '0060FF', '00FFFF', 'CCFFCC', 'FFFF00', 'FF8000', 'FF2000', '800000'];

print(yrPrcntl);
Map.addLayer(yrPrcntl.select("LST_Day_1km_p90"), {min: 280, max: 315, palette: palette});

var bounds = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([-180, -90, 180, 90]);
//var bounds = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([0, 40, 15, 40]);

Export.image.toAsset(
  {image: yrPrcntl,
   description: 'modis_p90',
   assetId: 'users/lorenzomentaschi/modis_p90',
   scale: 926.6254330555, // this is the scale of modis
   region: bounds,
   maxPixels: 1e9})
```

If I launch the script the layer is correctly visualized in the GEE environment, and the export proceeds without errors, but when I try to load the exported asset it appears uniformly null.
If I try to export to a much smaller area (e.g., over the rectangle [0, 40, 15, 50], commented line in the script) the exported image looks correct.

The same thing happens if I use a similar python code.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that worldwide geometry, you probably have to set the geodesic argument to false in your geometry.

```
var bounds = ee.Geometry.Rectangle({coords:[-180, -90, 180, 90],  geodesic: false});
```

See also [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-earth-engine-developers/global$20geometry%7Csort:relevance/google-earth-engine-developers/7_NZuljBH4w/HRvOY6fNBwAJ) and [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/89cfc134bdd1b8fd5486abacafaf2f84)